# Problem sharing a folder on intranet using samba

Tags: 14.04, samba, file-sharing

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32-bit installed on a laptop. There is a folder that I want to share over my office's intranet. So I configured the share with samba. I don't want anyone else to write or change any files so I checked the "visible" box but kept "writable" empty. Then I chose "Allow Access to Everyone". Then I used the following command:

```
sudo restart smbd && sudo restart nmbd
```

Restarted the system, too. The share worked and everyone was happy.

But now soon a problem has come up. Every time I add new files to the pre-existing folder or if I even change any property of an existing shared file, even something as simple as the filename, that file immediately becomes inaccessible to others on the network. I even restart smbd and nmbd services every time I make changes to the folder, but to no avail.

Anyone know any solutions to this? I apologize if this question is a duplicate but I searched long and no good solution of this problem came up.